# Laravel: connecting to the database in the docker/ docker-compose throwing error, "No such file or directory "

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose

I am working on a Laravel 6 application. I am using Docker as my development environment. I am trying to connecting to the database in the docker-compose configuring the variables in the .env file. But it is not working.

This is my docker-compose.yaml file.

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    container_name: coup_app
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: .docker/Dockerfile
    image: 'laravelapp'
    ports:
      - 8081:80
    networks:
      - coup-network
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
      - ./:/var/www/
      - ./ci:/var/www/ci:cached
      - ./vendor:/var/www/vendor:delegated
      - ./storage:/var/www/storage:delegated
      - ./node_modules:/var/www/node_modules:cached
      - ~/.ssh:/root/.ssh:cached
      - ./composer.json:/var/www/composer.json
      - ~/.composer/cache:/root/.composer/cache:delegated
  db:
    container_name: coup_db
    image: library/mariadb:10.4.11
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: coup
      MYSQL_USER: coup
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
    volumes:
      - coup-data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - coup-network
    ports:
      - "33060:3306"
networks:
  coup-network:
    driver: "bridge"
volumes:
  coup-data:
    driver: "local"
```

This is my Dockerfile.

```
FROM php:7.4.1-apache
USER root
WORKDIR /var/www/html
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
libpng-dev \
zlib1g-dev \
libxml2-dev \
libzip-dev \
libonig-dev \
zip \
curl \
unzip \
&& docker-php-ext-configure gd \
&& docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd \
&& docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql \
&& docker-php-ext-install mysqli \
&& docker-php-ext-install zip \
&& docker-php-source delete
COPY .docker/vhost.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html \
&& a2enmod rewrite
```

The followings are the DB credentials in my .env file.

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=db
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=coup
DB_USERNAME=coup
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

When I run the migration, I am getting the following error.

```
  Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: SHOW FULL TABLES WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  at /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:669
    665|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    666|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    667|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    668|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 669|             throw new QueryException(
    670|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    671|             );
    672|         }
    673| 

  Exception trace:

  1   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory")
      /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70

  2   PDO::__construct("mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=coup", "coup", "secret", [])
      /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70
```

What is wrong with my configuration and how can I fix it?

Comment: In my .env file DB_HOST=127.0.0.1 , but probably you can use the container name: coup_db

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that Laravel is not using the value of `DB_HOST`: in your `.env` it is set to `DB_HOST=db` but the stack trace shows

> 2   PDO::__construct("mysql:host=**localhost**;port=3306;dbname=coup", "coup", "secret", [])
> /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70

i.e. Laravel is effectively using `localhost` instead of `db` as the host.

---

### Background on the error message

In case you're wondering why the error message says *SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] **No such file or directory***,
from the [`mysql` docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/connecting.html):

> - If the host is not specified or is `localhost`, a connection to the local host occurs:
>
>   - On Unix, MySQL programs treat the host name localhost specially, in a way that is likely different from what you expect compared to other network-based programs: the client connects using a Unix socket file. The `--socket` option or the `MYSQL_UNIX_PORT` environment variable may be used to specify the socket name.

i.e. instead of trying to establish a *network* connection to `localhost` PHP will try to establish a connection via a *unix socket* by opening its file path (e.g. `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`).

Since in your case the database is running in a separate container this local path to the unix socket of the database is not available inside the Laravel container which is why the error message is *No such file or directory*.